# Can a PDF be opened with the Colorbox jquery Wordpress plugin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pdf, jpeg, colorbox

I'd like to upload only one version of an image to my wordpress site then use that image in a popup lightbox and as a downloadable pdf file for users.

It seems like I need to upload a jpg for the lightbox and a PDF for a downloadable link.

Anyway around this? Thanks

Here's a link to a page we have set up presently with both versions of the same image having to be uploaded - https://www.absolutept.com/electric-stimulation-patterns/